# Is allowing exceptions in static class constructors to escape a proper design pattern?

Tags: java, exception, static-initialization

I find myself choosing between the two following design patterns a lot:

```
static {
    try {
        foo();
    }
    catch(Exception exc) {
        throw new RuntimeException(exc.getMessage());
    }
}
```

and

```
TheConstructor() throws SomeException {
    if(alreadyInited) {
        return;
    }
    alreadyInited = true;
    foo();
}
```

The problem is I really do want to initialize stuff once per class - so statically, I think - such as setting up a logger, loading some map from a file, etc. - and I really do want the program to halt if this operation fails.  Both of these design patterns seem kludgey (the first one more obviously so), so I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this.

Comment: Why not use a singleton?

Comment: *The problem is I really do want to initialize stuff once per class* Are you looking for singleton? Also, I don't quite get why your first and second code sample would be functionally equivalent...

Comment: If your initialization code fails, can your program still run? Maybe a System.exit() would be apropiate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is allowing exceptions in static class constructors to escape a proper design pattern?

I would say No.

First, wrappering a checked exception in that context means that if something goes wrong you will get a class initialization failure.

- An exception that propagates out of the class initalizer cannot be caught and handled directly.
- An uncaught exception during class initialization is not recoverable.  Even if you could catch and handle the exception, the class and (I think) all others that depend on it / they will be left in a state where they cannot be initialized, and hence cannot be used.  That's effectively "game over" for (at least) the classloader, and possibly the entire JVM.

The bigger picture is that this probably represents an inappropriate use of statics.  There are better ways to handle this problem; e.g.

- Do the initialization using an explicit call (in a place where you can catch and handle the exception), rather than relying on class initialization.
- Get rid of the static (and potentially the singleton class that wraps it) and use dependency injection.

Comment: all true. just want to add two more: 1) initialize once per class does not necessary mean statically. you can do it using proper architecture and design. 2) using such ugly things as exceptions during class initialization will be a real pain in the ass during mock testing. just don't do it

Comment: @piotrek - Testing is a good point, but your point 1) is essentially repeating what I'm saying (or at least I mean to say) in the 3rd bullet point

Comment: Accepting this because I do think the proper design pattern is runtime/client-code control of whether to include this module.  I think in my actual application the code is simple enough that this approach is sufficiently maintainable and more maintainable than the "proper" design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The factory pattern can help you here.  You can still throw RunTime exceptions, although I would throw an exception called "CouldNotCreate" along with some cool info on what went wrong.

Comment: How can the factory pattern help?

Comment: Move everything that you would put in the static initialization section into the factory class instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your first example looks fine to me. If your class absolutely needs to do `foo()` to be usable, then if it can't do `foo()`, it's not usable. If it's not usable, then it must not be used. Throwing an exception from the static initializer is a straightforward and effective way of making sure that the class isn't used.

It's unfortunate that Java doesn't allow checked exceptions to be thrown from static initializers. I don't see why that should be the case.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I choose the singleton pattern FOR the "configuration".

But the logic inside the constructor is very strange, the static block is more clean IMHO, but I think it is not easy to test. Be careful.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the second a little less kludgey like this:

```
static boolean isStaticInit = false;
static void staticInit() throws InitException {
    if (isStaticInit) return;

    // [init loggers, map, etc...throw InitException as appropriate]

    isStaticInit = true;
}

MyClass() throws InitException {
    staticInit();

    // ...
}
```

Note there is a subtle difference between your first and second options.  In the first option, the `static{}` block is called when the class is first loaded, while for the second option, the init code isn't called until the first class instance is constructed.  This could make a difference if you have code that calls, say, `MyClass.myStaticMethod()`.  With option 1, the call would trigger class initialization; with option 2, it won't.